# How to do restart function with client.destroy and client.login when you already have a listener?

Tags: discord.js

I've done a shutdown command, but now I want to create a restart command that destroy's my client, then reconnects to the websocket. I'm just having a bit of trouble with it since I have command/event handlers set up with a ready listener.

I typed the code out, and started getting errors for the specific command. Or, i'd get the bot up and it would crash upon trying to use the command.

```js
const { prefix } = require("../../botconfig.json");

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "restart",
        description: "restarts the bot",
        usage: "wrestart",
        category: "moderation",
        accessableby: "Bot Owner",
        aliases: ["rs"]
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {

    if(message.author.id != "id") return message.channel.send("You're not bot the owner!")

    try {
        //I want to do the destroy/login command here...
        //client.destroy()
        //client.login('token') <--- and do I really have to define the token if I already have it in my botconfig?
    } catch(e) {
        message.channel.send(`ERROR: ${e.message}`)
    }



    }
}
```

I want to issue a command "wrestart" and it restart my application. Results so far are basically typing the code and getting it incorrect...so starting from scratch basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with this...

```js
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

    if(message.author.id != "299957385215344640") return message.channel.send("You're not bot the owner! https://i.imgur.com/8ep8YbI.gif")

    try {
        message.channel.send("<a:Loading:575715719103381506> Attempting a restart...").then(msg => {
          //msg.react('');
          setTimeout(function(){
             msg.edit("<:CheckMark:550460857625346066> I should be back up now!");
          }, 10000);
        })
        .then(client.destroy())
        .then(client.login('tokengoeshere'))




          } catch(e) {
            message.channel.send(`ERROR: ${e.message}`)

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
const token = bot.token; // Copies the token into the Variable
bot.destroy();           // Stops the Bot
bot.login(token);        // Uses the token we saved before to reauth
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for my bot, a simple one line of code.

```
client.destroy().then(client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN))
```